# SQLAlchemy .all() only returning first result on multi-join

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Howdie do,

So I'm joing 5 tables using the following query:

```
order = db.session.query(Trailer, Trip, TripPallet, WaveOrder, Package)\
    .join(Trip, Trailer.trailer_id == Trip.trailer_id)\
    .join(TripPallet, Trip.trip_id == TripPallet.trip_id)\
    .join(WaveOrder, TripPallet.pallet_id == WaveOrder.pallet_id)\
    .join(Package, WaveOrder.order_id == Package.order_id)\
    .filter(Trailer.trailer_id == '555555').all()
```

Now, the 5 tables are as follows:

```
**Trailer Table**
trailer_id      
555555

**Trip Table**
trip_id         trailer_id      
523462462       555555

**Trip Pallet table**
trip_id         pallet_id       
523462462       1052
523462462       1054

**Wave Order Table**
pallet_id       order_id
1052            123456
1052            123457
1054            324567
1054            797453

**Package table**
order_id        Tracking
123456            ABCKDF
123457            DVNIUO
324567            DNKLIN
797453            ADFNLN
```

So to give you an overview, a trailer contains a trip. That trip contains pallets and each pallet contains waves which are a grouping of packages.

The query that I'm using above will return all packages on one pallet, but it's not returning all the pallets.

When I run the query, via for loop, this is my result:

```
counter = 0
for trailer, trip, trippallet, wave_order, package in order:
    counter += 1
    print "%d The trailer id is %d and it contains the trip id %d with the pallet id %d and has the following order %d which " \
          "has the following tracking number %s" % \
          (counter, trailer.trailer_id, trip.trip_id, trippallet.pallet_id, wave_order.order_id, package.tracking_no)  

1 The trailer id is 555555 and it contains the trip id 523462462 with the pallet id 1052 and has the following order 123456 which has the following tracking number ABCKDF
2 The trailer id is 555555 and it contains the trip id 523462462 with the pallet id 1052 and has the following order 123457 which has the following tracking number DVNIUO
```

As you can see, it's only getting the first pallet_id from the trip pallet table which is 1052. It should also be getting the pallet_id 1054 and returning all the packages on that table.

Does anyone know how to make it return the second pallet_id from the Trip Pallet table and all it's corresponding packages?

Comment: If you remove all the joins after the join on `Pallet`, do you still receive only one pallet?

Comment: If I remove the joins, after the Pallet, so that the query is this:                             order = db.session.query(Trailer, Trip, TripPallet)\
    .join(Trip, Trailer.trailer_id == Trip.trailer_id)\
    .join(TripPallet, Trip.trip_id == TripPallet.trip_id).filter(Trailer.trailer_id == '555555').all()                                                                                                          I do receive all the Pallets

Comment: So I conclude that the other joins limit the data set to just one pallet. Add the joins one by one until you find the offending one. Double-check the data accessed by that join; I suspect there should be a discrepancy in keys that prevent the proper joining.

Comment: So, the issue wasn't the join at all. It was the database. I was working off incomplete information. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Howdie do,

The issue wasn't with the join statement. The join statement was 100% correct. In fact, it was the database.

The DBA had removed the key data that I needed to complete the join statement.